# How do you model the folding edge of the backrest?

Tags: modeling

How do you create the edges to fold around like that? I wanna create this exact same backrest piece as a modelling challenge for myself, but this might have been too advanced.

[Here's a link to the page where the images are from where you can see more of the model](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-model-ikea-adde-chair-1353192)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I might try some variation of bridge edge loops.

Comment: How though? I've tried using that, Hard Ops, subd modelling, etc., I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extrude a circle, spin it:

[image]

Cut a hole:

[image]

Extrude some edges:

[image]

[image]

Create new faces:

[image]

Fill the gaps between the faces:

[image]

You'll need to add edge loops to sharp the edges...

File here: [image]

Comment: Omg you absolute wizard! That's such a brilliant idea! Do you mind sharing the file so I can have a better look at how you went about it? I hadn't thought about flipping the top curved bit like that XD

Comment: I've put the link in my answer, I'm not sure it's the good proportions but you'll find the right ones

Comment: Alright, now I'm caught in another mess :( Your idea to model the fold in that way was brilliant, but now I can't figure out how to make those holes in the middle so that they are all symmetrically aligned. How do I make a symmetrical grid on the front and back so that I can convert the vertices into circles and connect them use bridge edge loops?

Comment: this is a completely different problem, you should create a face with a hole and array it, then you'll connect with the mesh you've done